# Is it necessary to transmit two or three points of an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, protocol-design, protocol-analysis, compression

Are there cryptographic protocols, where a party should transmit by communication channel simultaneously two or three $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$? Therefore we need a faster compress-decompression method for these two or three points, than just $x$-coordinates. The latter requires solving two or three quadratic equations to find $y$-coordinates.

I just invented one interesting method such that compression is bit slower, but decompression is much faster. Number of bits in the compressed form remains the same, i.e., $2\log(q)$ or $3\log(q)$ respectively. Is it useful for cryptographic society? If I am right, the Diffie-Hellman protocol and ECDSA require transmit just one point for each party.

Comment: Complex zero knowledge proofs like range proofs require dozens of points being transmitted at a time.

Comment: They are really used in practice or this is just a research topic?

Comment: I know of usages of ZKP in the cryptocurrency field (like in the CryptoNote or Monero's RingCT), I'm sure there are other fields using zero knowledge proofs a lot.